# Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0 provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: excel, ssis, ssms, import-from-excel

I am trying to import an Excel file (*.xlsx) into a SQL Server table using both SSIS and the "Import Data" feature inside SSMS.  However, in both instances, I am getting "The Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0 provider is not registered on the local machine (System.Data)."

However, when I go into my Programs, I see "Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 (English) 16.0.4519.1000" is installed, as well as "Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 (English) 14.0.7015.1000" , or at least shows up in the Apps and Features.  What am I missing to allow me to work with *.xlsx files as as the datasource to import into SQL Server either through SSIS or SSMS?

Please note, I understand Excel as a datasource is not ideal and there are better methods, but unfortunately, I am not in a position to make demands that they use other file formats.  The best I can do right now is ask for them to convert to *.xls format.

One thing I need to note as well, I do not have the ability to install anything on my own due to company security policies.  Everything must be done through their automated system.

Comment: Do you, perhaps, have the 32bit driver installed and you're trying to use the 64bit one, or vice versa?

Comment: I only have the 32-bit DTExec installed, but can't seem to figure out how to get the 64-bit version installed.

Comment: Yep, I saw your reply on your [cross post](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/microsoft-ace-oledb-16-0-provider-is-not-registered#post-3899265) @AMC .